# how to find the centroid of a gray image in python?

Tags: python, fft, centroid

I have found DFT of a gray image but not sure how to find the centroid of that image.please help me find an algorithm to do the same after finding the dft of the image.

Comment: look up centroid on wikipedia and give it a first go.  there are readymade functions in python packages to convert an image to a matrix. it should be doable from there. once you post your first attempt you'll surely get more help.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but I want to find centroid in Fourier domain.I have already achieved this using the spatial domain formula.

Comment: Taking the 2D fft of a matrix (image) is quite simple with numpy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft2.html  . Note that there is some rolling (rotate in Mathematica) of the array that is needed and that you are probably interested in the absolute value of the result (result of FFT is complex in most cases).